# Symfony2 components class not found

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-components

I am trying to use the `Request` & `Response` components of Symfony2 without the full framework. Here is my code:

```
<?php    
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;    
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;    
$r = Request::create( 'https://example.com', 'GET' );    
$response = $r->getResponse();    
$content = $response->getContent();
```

And I get this error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request'
>   not found in /root/billing/web/index.php on line 6

Comment: After you solve the class loading issue, you will have to deal with the fact that Request has no getResponse method.  Consider using a framework (Silex,Laravel,Symfony 2) to at least understand the basics.  Or maybe: https://github.com/fabpot/Create-Your-Framework/blob/master/book/part01.rst.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`ClassLoader`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/index.html) component to autoload your classes or you'll have to `require()` the class files instead. Short of writing your own [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Refer to the "Naming Conventions and Autoloading" part [of this document](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1)